# Как выдать ответ сервлета (древовидный объект) в формате XML?

Tags: xml, jsp, java, сервлеты, dom

Сервлет получает некоторые данные, обрабатывает их и результат обработки помещает в простое ДОМ-дерево.

Есть ли в Java стандартные методы, чтобы элементы дерева преобразовать в XML формат и выдать его?

Т.е. какими средствами в `response` сделать обработку и вывод объекта-дерева таким образом, чтобы клиенту ушел уже готовый к употребелению XML-файл?..

Comment: нужно установить content type результата в "text/xml" + записать в output stream xml: [пример][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484185/returning-xml-from-query-result-in-servlet

Comment: т.е., как ни крути, а прийдется руцями прописывать на вывод ХМЛ-тэги?..

Comment: омг, я то думал вы знаете разницу между дом и сакс парсерами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTFM!](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html)

Comment: это я знаю, здесь описывается механизм создания элементов ХМЛ, а мне бы еще и с корректной обработкой входного дерева.. (сейчас поправлю вопрос)